# Returning multiple jsonld schemas

Tags: nuxt.js, json-ld

I am trying to return multiple types of structured in one script tag with Nuxt.js.
I am using this plugin: https://github.com/ymmooot/nuxt-jsonld

On my site https://kassebil.dk/ford-kassebil/ford-transit-custom you can see that this works already with this code:

```
  jsonld() {
    const { brand, modelTitle, seoText, modelImage } = this.modelInfo
    const price = this.lowOffer
    return {
      '@context': 'https://schema.org',
      '@type': 'product',
      'brand': `${brand}`,
      'model': `${modelTitle}`,
      'name': `${modelTitle}`,
      'description': `${seoText.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '')}`,
      'image': `https://res.cloudinary.com/kassebil/image/upload/${modelImage}`,
      'url': `https://kassebil.dk${this.$route.path}`,
      'offers': {
        '@type': 'AggregateOffer',
        'lowPrice': `${price}`,
        'priceCurrency': 'DKK'
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I wish to add another schema for a FAQ schema. I simply can't figure out how this works. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

I just got a reply from the author behind the plugin. The solution is to use @graph.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph":
  [
    {
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "item": {
            "@id": "https://example.com/articles/1",
            "name": "foo"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://google.com/article"
      },
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
      ],
      "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
      "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Google",
        "logo": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg"
        }
      },
      "description": "A most wonderful article"
    }
  ]
}
```